# Powershell script - how to catch called child process exit code

Tags: powershell

I am trying to write a powershell script which call the .ftp file ([www.scriptftp.com](http://www.scriptftp.com/)). When Powershell call the .ftp script file which is use to upload a zip file to ftp server

here is my `upload.ftp` file code

```
OPENHOST("www.abcd.in","sdfdsfs","pwd")
CHDIR("/dirctory/from/user/")

$result=PUTFILE("D:\MyZipTest.zip")

IF($result!="OK")
    PRINT("ERROR in GetFile, exiting")
    # Exit with error code 1
    EXIT(1)
ELSE
    EXIT()
    PRINT("File uploaded successfuly")
END IF

CLOSEHOST
```

In Above code i return `EXIT(1)` or `EXIT(0)` to calling method ie powershell script file

my powershell script file code:

```
Invoke-Item "D:\USER\Raj\BLACKswastik DEV\FTPScript\Upload1.ftp"

Start-Sleep -Second 15

echo $lastexitcode

echo $?
```

here i want to fetch exit code which return by .ftp file script so i use `$lastexitcode` and `$?` but both of them not showing me proper results.
IS there any other way to fetch the exit code of child process please suggest me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using `Start-Process`.  You can get back a `Process` object that you can query later for an exit code e.g.:

```
$ftpPath = "D:\USER\Raj\BLACKswastik DEV\FTPScript\Upload1.ftp"
$p = Start-Process <path_to_scriptftp.exe> -Wait -PassThru -ArgumentList $ftpPath
$p.ExitCode
```

The problem with using Invoke-Expression (or launching the exe directly) is that you're launching a Windows subsystem EXE and unlike a console subsystem exe, Invoke-Expression will return right after the exe has launched (and before it exits). Invoke-Item also returns before the Windows EXE has exited.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Invoke-Expression -Command "D:\User\...\Upload1.ftp"
```

instead of

```
Invoke-Item "D:\User\...\Upload1.ftp"
```